# How to get visible options' count of HTML select tag, with multiple attribute set, while size not set?

Tags: javascript, html

In my case, I want to get the **select** element's visible options' count (By visible options' count, I mean **how many options are visible without scrolling**. Thanks Matthew). If **size** attribute is set, then *element.size* is the value I need. When it isn't, things get a little tricky.

For example, in following code:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
```

In IE/Chrome/Firefox, it will show like the picture below. In this case, *count* should be 3:

[image: in this case, count should be 3]

If option count in previous case is greater than 4, it still shows 4 visible lines. In this case, *count* should be 4:

[image: in this case, count should be 4]

Is there a good way, other than using *if...else...*, to get the visible options' count of **select** tag, in any circumstances?

FYI, I'm developing a test software to do functional testing for customers' website, so I'm not able to modify code of the web page.

Comment: What do you mean by _visible items_ ? Are you hiding the `option` somewhere ? Pls clarify!

Comment: I think he means how many items are visible without scrolling. Basically, have to find the height of the select and the height of each line of txt and just divide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out a new solution to this question, and it seems better. Here is code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("id_to_select");
var threshold;

if (e.size > 0) {
    threshold = e.size;
} else { // size not set
    threshold = e.multiple ? 4 : 1; // Why 4, please see below
}
return Math.min(e.length, threshold);
```

There are some basic facts on **select** element which make me write code like this:

- If *size* property is set to valid values (larger than 0), the visible items' count is depending on the relationship between element.size and element.length, regardless of *multiple* set or not.
- If *size* not set, but *multiple* set, the count will be depending on the relationship between element.length and 4, which is the default value of size in multiple mode. For more information, please see [specification of select element](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select).
- If both *size* and *multiple* not set, the count will be either 1 or 0, which is depending on whether the select has options or not.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly:

```
 var maxVisibleCount = Math.floor(containerHeight / optionHeight);
 var actualCount = $(this).children('option').length;
 var result = (maxVisibleCount > actualCount) ? actualCount : maxVisibleCount;
```

live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/md13qq0d/

edit: sorry, I have not seen that you are not using jQuery:
https://jsfiddle.net/md13qq0d/2/

Comment: Yes, I think this will work fine for me. But when I run the live demo, I didn't get the *result*. I'll test on my local machine. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Could you please accept the answer as solution? Thanks :-)

Comment: There is a new problem. If I set select's style to *padding-top:1px*, the result would be a float value. Rounding the fractional part does not help, because the padding value could be larger than options' height. Do you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Then we should remove the padding value from the height, here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/md13qq0d/4/

Comment: I'm afraid there could be more styles like *padding-top*, should we emum all possible styles and deal with them one by one? Isn't it a little complex?

Comment: only padding and border can modify the innerWidth of an element. I think still this is a best solution for your case: https://jsfiddle.net/md13qq0d/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to your select tag and using that id u can easily retrieve no. of visible items(options) in that particular select tag .My eg -

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
alert($('#selectid option').length);  
</script>
```

Here '**selectid**' is the id given to the particular select whose visible options u want to get .

Comment: I'm developing a test software to do functional testing for customers' website, so I'm not able to modify code of the web page. Thanks.

Comment: If u have only one select box in that case only this could also work - alert($('select option').length);

Comment: This won't work for me. Because I want to know the count of options which are visible **without scrolling**, while *length* returns total count of options.

Answer (score 0):

please check you will  get count ....

```
  function GetSelected () {
        var select = document.getElementById ("mySelect");
        var txt = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
            var isSelected = select.options[i].selected;
            isSelected = (isSelected)? "selected" : "not selected";
            txt += "The " + i + " option is " + isSelected + "\n";
        }
        alert (txt);
    }
```